# WordPress Page Image move down on mobile view - change order

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

```css
.vce-row {
    flex-direction: column;
}
global-elements…277104ee8181:1
.rtl .vce-row>.vce-row-content>.vce-col.vce-col--all-last, .rtl.vce-row>.vce-row-content>.vce-col.vce-col--all-last, .vce-row {
    margin-left: 0;
}
global-elements…277104ee8181:1
.vce-row, .vce-row-content>.vce-col:last-child, .vce-row>.vce-row-content>.vce-col.vce-col--all-last {
    margin-right: 0;
}
global-elements…277104ee8181:1
.vce-row, .vce-row-content {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}
bootstrap.min.css?ver=2.0.2:6
*, ::after, ::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
user agent stylesheet
div {
    display: block;
}
.vce-row--col-gap-30>.vce-row-content>.vce-col {
    margin-right: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
global-elements…277104ee8181:1
.vce-row--col-gap-30>.vce-row-content>.vce-col--md-50p {
    flex: 0;
    flex-basis: calc((100% - 2970px) * .5 + 1470px);
    max-width: calc((100% - 2970px) * .5 + 1470px);
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
global-elements…277104ee8181:1
.vce-row--col-gap-30>.vce-row-content>.vce-col {
    margin-right: 30px;
}
global-elements…277104ee8181:1
.vce-row--col-gap-30>.vce-row-content>.vce-col {
    margin-right: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
global-elements…277104ee8181:1
.vce-row--col-gap-30>.vce-row-content>.vce-col {
    margin-right: 30px;
}
global-elements…277104ee8181:1
.vce-row--col-gap-30>.vce-row-content>.vce-col {
    margin-right: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 0)
global-elements…277104ee8181:1
.vce-col--xs-1 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
global-elements…277104ee8181:1
.vce-col {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    min-width: 1em;
    position: relative;
}
bootstrap.min.css?ver=2.0.2:6
*, ::after, ::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
user agent stylesheet
div {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="vce-row-container">
<div class="vce-row vce-row--col-gap-30 vce-row-columns--top vce-row-content--top" id="el-ae93b178" data-vce-do-apply="all el-ae93b178">
<div class="vce-row-content" data-vce-element-content="true">
<div class="vce-col vce-col--md-50p vce-col--xs-1 vce-col--xs-last vce-col--xs-first vce-col--sm-last vce-col--sm-first vce-col--md-first vce-col--lg-first vce-col--xl-first" id="el-eacaebbd" data-vce-do-apply="background el-eacaebbd">
<div class="vce-col-inner" data-vce-element-content="true" data-vce-do-apply="padding margin  border el-eacaebbd">
<div class="vce-text-block">
<div class="vce-text-block-wrapper vce" id="el-21310b56" data-vce-do-apply="all el-21310b56">
<h2>Page Title</h2><p>Page Content</div></div></div></div>
<div class="vce-col vce-col--md-50p vce-col--xs-1 vce-col--xs-last vce-col--xs-first vce-col--sm-last vce-col--sm-first vce-col--md-last vce-col--lg-last vce-col--xl-last" id="el-bf03877a" data-vce-do-apply="background el-bf03877a">
<div class="vce-col-inner" data-vce-element-content="true" data-vce-do-apply="padding margin  border el-bf03877a">
<div class="vce-single-image-container vce-single-image--align-left">
<div class="vce vce-single-image-wrapper" id="el-2393669a" data-vce-do-apply="all el-2393669a">
<figure>
<div class="vce-single-image-inner vce-single-image--border-rounded">
<img class="vce-single-image" src="image link"></div></figure></div></div>
<div class="vce-button--style-basic-container vce-button--style-basic-container--align-center">
<span class="vce-button--style-basic-wrapper vce" id="el-b473842a" data-vce-do-apply="margin el-b473842a">
<a class="vce-button--style-basic vce-button--style-basic--border-rounded vce-button--style-basic--size-medium vce-button--style-basic--color-557cbf--fff" href="Contact us link" title="" data-vce-do-apply="padding border background  el-b473842a">Contact us</a></span></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

I am new to WordPress so please pardon my question. I have edited a site with Visual Composer, it looks great on desktop view as you can see on the attached picture. On the mobile view, it shifts the image under the text, I want the image to be above the text on mobile view and keep the current layout for desktop view. I looked over the internet and many people suggested to use push and pull but I don't know where to start from.
Thanks

[Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTtxf.jpg)
[Desktop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfLq2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the browser reads your screen from left to right, so when compressed to a smaller screen, it puts the content from the left to the top because that would logical for somebody reading your page.

If you provide some source code then we can look and help you with this problem.